# Look for Star Trek (2009) fanfic

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, fan-fiction, star-trek-2009

I am looking for a story I read some time ago. In it Kirk, Spock and McCoy are on a peace mission with some type of telepathic alien or something that uses McCoy to talk with Jim and the others, that is all I can remember.

The story was in English I think it was a pre-slash Kirk/McCoy/Spock fic on ao3 and was a one-shot, I remember that kirk and Spock said that they would take McCoy's place but the aliens said something about the doctor's mind was nice, there was no danger but when it was all over I think they got together.

Comment: Do you remember anything more? Any sort of detail? Was the story in English? Roughly how long was it, was it a one-shot? Was there and couple/pairings? What site was it on? Did anything dangerous happen?

Comment: The story was in English I think it was a pre-slash Kirk/McCoy/Spock fic on ao3 and was a one-shot, I remember that kirk and Spock said that they would take McCoy's place but the aliens said something about the doctor's mind was nice, there was no danger but when it was all over I think they got together.Hope this helps.

Comment: That does help a lot, thank you. Another question, do you remember if this was based on the original star trek series, or if the main characters were from the newer movies?

Comment: Story I can't remember.